# Как установить libcurl под win64?

Tags: ruby

Выдаёт такую жуть при запуске программы. Где установить libcurl под win64?

```
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
[ERROR] Could not open library 'libcurl': P?".
Could not open library 'libcurl.dll': P?".
Could not open library 'libcurl.so.4': ?? ?????? ????????? ??????.
.
Could not open library 'libcurl.so.4.dll': ?? ?????? ????????? ??????.
```

Answer (score 1):

Метод лечения:

1. Заходим на google.com
2. В строке поиска вводим: "Could not open library 'libcurl.dll'"
3. Ходим по ссылкам...

Первая-же ссылка привела меня: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22525093/typhoeus-windows-installation

А вообще странная ошибка. Ни разу под виндой не сталкивался. Ставили отсюда: http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/ ?

Comment: да... из rubyinstaller

Comment: DevKit ставили? Послеустановочную процедуру выполнили?

Answer (score 0):

libcurl.so.4 - это характерное имя библиотек в линуксе. Видимо библиотека мультиплатформенная и просто пытается найти файл по списку, не проверяя операционную систему.

libcurl.so.4.dll - а это видимо гибридное имя. Вполне возможно, что curl такое использует.